# getServerSideProps gives data but does not re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

My approach is probably against to SSR, but what am I trying to achieve is, to render all products when user visits `/products`, and it renders perfect with a simple `products.map(...)`. I also have a category filter, I did set a onClick to that checkbox and it basicly routes to `/products?category=${categoryName}` 
 it sets the url, console logged filtered products are correct, but does not update first rendered products.

Here is my `getServerSideProps` ;

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const { db } = await connectToDatabase();

  const getCategoriesFromDB = await db
    .collection('categories')
    .find({})
    .toArray();
  const getCategories = await JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(getCategoriesFromDB));

  if (
    !(
      Object.keys(context.query).length === 0 &&
      context.query.constructor === Object
    )
  ) {
    console.log('if fired!');
    console.log(context.query);
    const category = context.query.category;

    const getFilteredProducts = await db
      .collection('products')
      .find({
        category: category,
      })
      .toArray();
    const getProducts = await JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(getFilteredProducts));
    console.log(getProducts);
    return {
      props: {
        getCategories,
        getProducts,
       },
    };
  } else {
    console.log('else fired!');
    const getProductsFromDB = await db
      .collection('products')
      .find({})
      .toArray();
    const getProducts = await JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(getProductsFromDB));
    return {
      props: {
        getCategories,
        getProducts,
      },
    };
  }
};
```

here is the some of states and useEffect;

```
const Products = ({ getCategories, getProducts }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [products, setProducts] = useState(getProducts);
  const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
  const router = useRouter();
  console.log(products);
  console.log(categories);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (categories.length === 0) {
      setProducts(getProducts);
    }
    
  }, [categories, products]);

  const addToFilter = async (e) => {
    const categoryName = e.currentTarget.dataset.category;

    if (categories.length === 0) {
      setCategories([...categories, categoryName]);
    }
 
    router.push(
      `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL}/products?category=${categoryName}`
    );
  };
```

this is the div where I render the products;

```
{products.map((product) => (
    <Grid
      item
      md={3}
      xs={6}
      className={classes.productCardWrapper}
      key={product._id}
    >
      <div className={classes.productCard}>
        <div className={classes.productImageWrapper}>
          <Image
            src={product.image[0].secure_url}
            alt={`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL} ${product.name}`}
            height={300}
            width={450}
          />
        </div>
        <Typography className={classes.productCardTypo}>
          {product.name}
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant='h6' className={classes.productCardTypo}>
          €{product.price}
        </Typography>{' '}
```

I am getting used to NextJS so i am not really sure if my approach is not correct.

As I said, I get the filtered products on the vscode terminal, but the browser still has the old products console logged.

Comment: Could you also add the code of your page component, where you filter and display the products?

Comment: @juliomalves added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it more convenient, Im also filtering products from backend, not frontend anymore. But I still use `getServerSideProps`; here is code

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const { db } = await connectToDatabase();

  const getCategoriesFromDB = await db
    .collection('categories')
    .find({})
    .toArray();
  const getCategories = await JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(getCategoriesFromDB));

  if (
    !(
      Object.keys(context.query).length === 0 &&
      context.query.constructor === Object
    )
  ) {
    const category = context.query.category;

    if (typeof context.query.category === 'string') {
      const getFilteredProducts = await db
        .collection('products')
        .find({
          category: category,
        })
        .toArray();
      const getProducts = await JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(getFilteredProducts));
      return {
        props: {
          getCategories,
          getProducts,
        },
      };
    } else if (
      typeof context.query.category === 'object' &&
      context.query.category.length > 1
    ) {
      let orArray = [];

      for (let i = 0; i < context.query.category.length; i++) {
        let categoryItem = {};
        let element = context.query.category[i];
        categoryItem = { category: element };

        orArray.push(categoryItem);
      }

      const filteredProducts = await db
        .collection('products')
        .aggregate([
          {
            $match: {
              $or: orArray,
            },
          },
        ])
        .toArray();
      const getProducts = await JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(filteredProducts));
      return {
        props: {
          getCategories,
          getProducts,
        },
      };
    }
  } else {
    const getProductsFromDB = await db
      .collection('products')
      .find({})
      .toArray();
    const getProducts = await JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(getProductsFromDB));
    return {
      props: {
        getCategories,
        getProducts,
      },
    };
  }
};
```

and there I render the products ;

```
<Grid
      item
      container
      md={10}
      spacing={3}
      className={classes.productsGridContainer}
    >
      {getProducts.map((product) => (
        <Grid
          item
          md={3}
          xs={6}
          className={classes.productCardWrapper}
          key={product._id}
        >
          <div className={classes.productCard}>
            <Link
              href={`${
                process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL
              }/products/${product.name.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '-')}`}
            >
              <a className={classes.productLink}>
                <div className={classes.productImageWrapper}>
                  <Image
                    src={product.image[0].secure_url}
                    alt={`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_URL} ${product.name}`}
                    height={350}
                    width={400}
                  />
                </div>
                <Typography
                  className={classes.productCardTypo}
                  style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}
                >
                  {product.name}
                </Typography>
              </a>
            </Link>
            <Typography
              variant='h6'
              style={{ color: '#5652de' }}
              className={classes.productCardTypo2}
            >
              €{product.price}
            </Typography>
            <div className={classes.productCardBtn}>
              <Button
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: `${!product.active && '#f6f6f6'}`,
                }}
                fullWidth
                color='primary'
                variant='contained'
                disableRipple
                disableFocusRipple
                disableElevation
                disableTouchRipple
                disabled={product.active ? false : true}
              >
                {product.active ? (
                  <>
                    <AddShoppingCartIcon fontSize='small' />
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <span className={classes.productCardBtnWrapper}>
                      Add to Cart
                    </span>
                  </>
                ) : (
                  <>
                    <RemoveShoppingCartIcon fontSize='small' /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <span className={classes.productCardBtnWrapper}>
                      Out of Stock
                    </span>
                  </>
                )}
              </Button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </Grid>
      ))}
    </Grid>
```